# Obtener resultado de funcion

Tags: php, wordpress

En mi sitio, el usuario responde preguntas y luego estos valores se imprimen en el formulario estandar de perfil para que en otro momento puedan modificarlos. 
Estos valores se imprimen en el backend pero no en el front end. Explico mis dos codigos a continuación:

**BACKEND Fragmento de complemento mu-plugin/profile.php**
Este complemento lo que hace es que la respuesta de formulario de preguntas `$direccion = $form->getValueText('quform_7_14');`la inserta en el campo del perfil `agent_office_address`. Esto funciona.

```
<?php

            add_action('quform_post_process_7',function (array $result, Quform_Form $form) {
             global $post;
            global $current_user;
            wp_get_current_user();
            $user_id = $current_user->ID;
            $full_name = $current_user->user_login;
            $agent_firstname = $current_user->first_name;
            $agent_lastname = $current_user->last_name;
            $agent_description = $current_user->description;


            if (!empty($agent_firstname) || !empty($agent_lastname)) {
                $full_name = $agent_firstname . ' ' . $agent_lastname;
            }
            $post_status = 'publish';
            $auto_approved_agent = ere_get_option('auto_approved_agent', 1);
            if ($auto_approved_agent != 1) {
                $post_status = 'pending';
            }
//Insert Agent
            $agent_id = wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_title' => $full_name,
                'post_type' => 'agent',
                'post_status' => $post_status,
                'post_content' => $agent_description
            ));


                update_user_meta($user_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'author_agent_id', $agent_id);
                $agent_email = $current_user->user_email;
                $agent_website_url = $current_user->user_url;
                $telefono  = $form->getValueText('quform_7_20');
                $direccion = $form->getValueText('quform_7_14');

                 $agent_position = get_the_author_meta(ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'author_position', $user_id);
                $agent_mobile_number = get_the_author_meta(ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'author_mobile_number', $user_id);
                $agent_office_address = get_the_author_meta(ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'author_office_address', $user_id);

                update_post_meta($agent_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'agent_user_id', $user_id);
                update_post_meta($agent_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'agent_description', $agent_description);          
                 update_post_meta($agent_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'agent_email', $agent_email);            
                update_post_meta($agent_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'author_mobile_number', $telefono);
                update_post_meta($agent_id, ERE_METABOX_PREFIX . 'agent_office_address',  $direccion);
               global $direccion;



return $result;
 }, 10, 2);
```

**FRONTEND Fragmento de mi formulario dentro de la carpeta plugin/esset/myprofile.php**
Con este codigo lo que busco es replicar esa respuesta aqui. es decir  `<input type="text" id="user_office_address">` sea completado con la variable $direccion

```
  <?php global $direccion;
    if (!in_array("user_office_address", $hide_user_info_fields)): ?>
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="user_office_address"><?php esc_html_e('Office Address', 'essential-real-estate'); ?></label>
  <input type="text" id="user_office_address" name="user_office_address"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo esc_attr($direccion); ?>">
   </div></div><?php endif; ?>
```

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta para nada. ¿Podrías replantear tu preguntar para poder responderla de nuevo?

Comment: ¿Cuál variable?

Comment: edite la pregunta con más detalles. @DiegoSaravia / la variable es  `$direccion`  @Triby